# Request to site-wide mods for tag aliases

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

It looks like no one yet has the reputation to create tag synonyms, could someone please take a few minutes to create the following based on our meta discussion at [How should we tag age-specific questions?](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-should-we-tag-age-specific-questions) ? Thanks.

TAG = Synonyms
premature = premie, preemie, premature-birth*, premature-babies*
newborn = newborns
infant = infants*
toddler = toddlers*
pre-schooler** = pre-schoolers, preschoolers*, preschool-age*

for pre-schooler, can you please rename preschoolers to pre-schooler first? I put the tag definition in that one.

The tags with asterisks are already existing, so there are already some questions with them, not sure if this will require additional work to retag first or not. If so just ask and I'll go retagging.

You'll note from the above linked discussion that the above list is only half complete... I'm out of energy for tonight and will catch the second half another night.

---

Everything above seems to be in place, thanks!

Round 2 additions:
primary-schooler = primary-schoolers
middle-schooler = middle-schoolers
pre-teen = pre-teens, tween, tweens
teen** = teenagers, teens
adult-child** = adult-children

For teen & adult-child, can you please rename teenagers and adult-children first? For pre-teen, I'm assuming by the time you see this my tag additions for pre-teen have been approved so that tag will "exist" to alias to.

Comment: Hey Cabbey, it looks like you can close/accept this one. We've got it covered :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I got all of the above—but I'd appreciate it if someone would double-check to see if I got them all right.

Comment: thanks Dori, I'll double check them when I do the next round.