# Teen-y Tag Clarification

Tags: discussion, tags

Yes, I had a little fun with the title.

@Doorknob冰 brought up a conflict in the overlap of [pre-teen](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-teen) and [teen](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teen) in chat.  The descriptions claim a fuzzy factor, but their definitions disallow it IMO.

[pre-teen](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pre-teen) says:

> but before they turn into teens, so say from about 11 years of age to about 14 years

You can't be *before* teen and *after* it at the same time. (And the use of "so say" weakens the description.)

The description for [teen](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teen) is a bit better, though I still prefer nixing the "so say".

Was there previous discussion on this or ought the descriptions be modified to be clearer?

Edit: I do see [this previous discussion](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-should-we-tag-age-specific-questions?rq=1). Is it time for reconsideration of some points?

Edit #2: Per the albeit limited dialog here, I have made changes.  Most notably, I have removed the paragraphs about romantic/sexual "interest" in the other gender.  If these are "age-specific" then that, as we have all seen by watching the news, has not as much to do with romantic/sexual desires and their expression than many would hope!

The tags are much more generally defined now than before.

**I'm not the end-all-be-all of course, so if I have erred, please don't hesitate to correct my fallacy(ies)!**

Comment: I'd actually estimate pre-teen as more like 9 to 12 than 11 to 14, so it's clearly subjective -- an argument in favor of removing quantitative boundaries from the tag definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those age ranges are definitely silly. By the very definition of the word, "pre-teen" cannot be 13 or older.

I haven't reviewed the tag descriptions for *ages* so I have no idea how long the current wording has been in place. I seem to recall from back when we defined these tags in the first place that we discussed how it would be useful to *not* state numeric ages but rather development/education milestones.

In any case, I vote for the removal of numeric ages, at the very least in the "pre-teen" tag.

Comment: Based on the feedback here, I will make an edit to the tags.